# Formatting a CommandParameter String in WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I would like CommandParameter to be "9" and not "_9".

```
<Button Content="_9"
        Focusable="False"
        Command="{Binding NumberPress}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content}"
        Style="{DynamicResource NumberButton}"
        Margin="92,134,92,129" />
```

I know I could just do CommandParameter="9" but I would like to pull out a Style to apply to multiple buttons. I have tried using StringFormat= but can't seem to make it work. Is there a way to do this without resorting to code behind?

Comment: It's a bit horrible but you could just bind to `Tag` instead and set `Tag` to 9 and leave the button content as _9 - don't know if stringformat works for command params (you'd think it would..)

Comment: I might not be using StringFormat properly, can you show me how it would be done in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If your "_" as you mention in your comment is strictly part of View only, then you can indeed use a Format property to get that to appear for `Content` with `ContentStringFormat`.

say something like:

```
<Button Margin="92,134,92,129"
        Command="{Binding NumberPress}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Content,
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Content="9"
        ContentStringFormat="_{0}"
        Focusable="False"
        Style="{DynamicResource NumberButton}" />
```

That way if you have the Button's `Content` Binding to a value, you do not have to keep prepending "_" there.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the Command referenced by NumberPress, then the easiest solution would be to do parse the command parameter there to get the number. If that's not an option, then another solution is to create an IValueConverter class and add it to the CommandParameter binding.

```
<Button Content="_9"
        Focusable="False"
        Command="{Binding NumberPress}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},
                 Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource NumberConverter}}"
        Margin="92,134,92,129" />
```

Implementation:

```
public class NumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            string strVal = ((string)value).TrimStart('_');
            int intVal;
            if (int.TryParse(strVal, out intVal))
                return intVal;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```